# finding which elements(div) has been shown in a page with scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so here is my page

```
<Style>.item{ width :200px ; height:200px ; background-color:red ; float:right ; margin : 10px}</style>

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

here is the full code

http://jsfiddle.net/gup3o1ap/1/

as you can see there are lots of div.item on the page and the page has a big scroll bar , i want to know which .item has been seen by the user , so basically i need to know the last item visible on the page (.items before that has already been shown )

so i can calculate when scroll gets to the end of the page

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
      console.log('at the end' );
   }
});
```

but i don't know how can i find which element is the last one shown on the page

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hyuf929k/ it alerts when at the bottom?

Comment: @SimonStaton i want to know which element is the last one showing on the page , not when scroll get to the bottom of page

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

scrollTop() gives you the height above the page, so you can use that along with element height and window height (and do some math) to find what elements have been displayed.